# Is it possible to implement a ViewPager2 inside another ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

The layout I'm currently using consists of a TabLayout with Viewpager2, what I'm trying to achieve is implementing another ViewPager2 to display several images in one of the tabs. But the issue I'm facing is when I swipe, I am only able to switch between tabs instead of switching images. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [This link will help you](https://www.journaldev.com/19336/android-nested-viewpager-vertical-viewpager)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, just add this piece of code into your program.

```
private void reduceDragSensitivity() {
    try {
        Field ff = ViewPager2.class.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView") ;
        ff.setAccessible(true);
        RecyclerView recyclerView =  (RecyclerView) ff.get(viewPager);
        Field touchSlopField = RecyclerView.class.getDeclaredField("mTouchSlop") ;
        touchSlopField.setAccessible(true);
        int touchSlop = (int) touchSlopField.get(recyclerView);
        touchSlopField.set(recyclerView,touchSlop*4);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Read more about it here: https://medium.com/@al.e.shevelev/how-to-reduce-scroll-sensitivity-of-viewpager2-widget-87797ad02414

Comment: i added this to top viewpager and to inner. does not work for me.